# How to parse a word/phrase with 2 words with dictionary database (in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, dictionary

I want to parse a sentence into words but some sentences have two words that can be combined into one and result in a different meaning.

For example:

> Eminem is a hip hop star.

If I parse it by splitting the words by space I will get

```
Eminem
is
a
**hip**
**hop**
star
```

but I want something like this:

```
Eminem
is
a
**hip hop**
star
```

This is just an example; there might be some other word combinations listed as a word in a dictionary.

How can I parse this easily?

I have a dictionary in a MySQL database. Is there any API to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No API's I know of. However you could try the SQL like clause.

```
$words = explode(' ', 'Eminem is a hip hop star');
$len = count($words);

$fixed = array();

for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
    //LIKE 'hip %' will match hip hop
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM dict WHERE word LIKE '".$words[$x]." %'");

    //Combine current and next word
    $combined = $words[$x].' '.$words[($x+1)];

    while( $result = mysql_fetch_array($q)) { 
        if($result['word'] == $combined) {  //Word is in dictionary
            $fixed[] = $combined;
            $x++;
        } else {  //Word isn't in dictionary
            $fixed[] = $words[$x];
        }
    }
}
```

*Please excuse my lack of PDO. I'm lazy right now.

**EDIT:** I've done some thinking. While the code above isn't optimal, the optimized version I've come up with probably can't do very much better. The fact of the matter is regardless of how you approach the problem, you will need to compare every word in your input sentence to your dictionary and perform additional computations. I see two approaches you can take depending on hardware limits.

Both of these methods assume a `dict` table with (example) structure:

```
+--+-----+------+
|id|first|second|
+--+-----+------+
|01|hip  |hop   |
+--+-----+------+
|02|grade|school|
+--+-----+------+
```

**Option 1: Your webserver has lots of available RAM (and a decent processor)**

The idea here is to completely bypass the database layer by caching the dictionary in PHP's memory (with APC or memcache, the latter if you plan to run on several severs). This will place all the load on your webserver, however it could be significantly faster since accessing cached data from the RAM is much faster than querying your DB.

(Again, I've left out PDO and Sanitization for simplicity's sake)

```
// Step One: Cache Dictionary..the entire dictionary
//           This could be run on server start-up or before every user input
if(!apc_exists('words')) {
    $words = array();

    $q = mysql_query('SELECT first, second FROM dict');
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $words[] = array_values($res);
    }

    apc_store('words', serialize($words)); //You could use memcache if you want
}


// Step Two: Compare cached dictionary to user input
$data = explode(' ', 'Eminem is a hip hop star');
$words = apc_fetch('words');

$count = count($data);
for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) { //Simpler to use a for loop
    foreach($words as $word) { //Match against each word
        if($data[$x] == $word[0] && $data[$x+1] == $word[1]) {
            $data[$x] .= ' '.$word[1];
            array_splice($data, $x, 1);
            $count--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Fast SQL Server**
The second option involves querying each of the words in the input text from the SQL server. For example, for the sentence "Eminem is hip hop" you would create a query that looked like `SELECT * FROM dict WHERE (first = 'Eminem' && second = 'is') || (first = 'is' && second = 'hip') || (first = 'hip' && second = 'hop')`. Then to fix the array of words you would simply loop through MySQL's results and fuse the appropriate words together. If you are willing to take this route, it might be more efficient to cache commonly used words and fix them before querying the database. This way you can eliminate conditions from your query.

Comment: I'm also kind of lazy to test the code right now, I will test it later. I'm feeling sleepy now :(. thanks anyway!

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: I think this code has a bug. For example if you have both "hip hop" and "hip injury" - you will get two $words[$x] added to $fixed array. Why not to just query combined words from dictionary and add only one word if it is not found? That second loop seems crazy.

Comment: I just tried this code. this code is good for a start, but requires some modifications. is there any other algorithm that can be more flexible for more than two words combination? I can write it, simply by modifying this code, but the problem is computer power and speed of processing..

Comment: @bn You are right in that this certainly isn't the most efficient snippet. XzKto also brings up a good point. Let me give this some thought...I think I can come up with something better.

Comment: @bn I've updated my answer to include Option 1 & 2. See if either suits you.